# Binary Search Complexity

Tags: search, binary

What is the time complexity of binary search taking an array of n elements as input from user..

As the time complexity of binary search is O(log n)
Whereas, the time complexity of taking the array as input from user is O(n)

Answer (score 0):

**For the whole program the answer is: `O(logn) + O(n) = O(n)`**

*Why is it?* because your input of n numbers into an array and binary search is independent of each other.

Now we need to understand `time complexity` in general:

In the simplest terms, for a problem where the input size is n:

**Best case** = fastest time to complete, with optimal inputs chosen.
For example, the best case for a sorting algorithm would be data that's already sorted.

**Worst case** = slowest time to complete, with pessimal inputs are chosen.
For example, the worst case for a sorting algorithm might be data that are sorted in reverse order (but it depends on the particular algorithm).

**Average case** = arithmetic mean. Run the algorithm many times, using many different inputs of size n that come from some distribution that generates these inputs (in the simplest case, all the possible inputs are equally likely), and compute the total running time (by adding the individual times), and divide by the number of trials. You may also need to normalize the results based on the size of the input sets.

**Example (Binary search):**

Suppose we have the following binary search function:

```
binarySearch(arr, x, low, high)
        repeat till low = high
               mid = (low + high)/2
                   if (x == arr[mid])
                   return mid
   
                   else if (x > arr[mid]) // x is on the right side
                       low = mid + 1
   
                   else                  // x is on the left side
                       high = mid - 1
```

Now, let's analyze its `time complexity`.

**Best Case Time Complexity of Binary Search**

The best case of Binary Search occurs when:

The element to be searched is in the middle of the list
In this case, the element is found in the first step itself and this involves 1 comparison.

Therefore, Best Case Time Complexity of Binary Search is `O(1)`.

**Average Case Time Complexity of Binary Search**

Let the input be N distinct numbers: a1, a2, ..., a(N-1), aN

We need to find element P.

There are two cases:

**Case 1:** The element P can be in N distinct indexes from 0 to N-1.

**Case 2:** There will be a case when the element P is not present in the list.
There are N case 1 and 1 case 2. So, there are N+1 distinct cases to consider in total.

If element P is in index K, then Binary Search will do K+1 comparisons.

This is because:

The element at index N/2 can be found in 1 comparison as Binary Search starts from middle.

Similarly, in the 2nd comparisons, elements at index N/4 and 3N/4 are compared based on the result of 1st comparison.

On this line, in the 3rd comparison, elements at index N/8, 3N/8, 5N/8, 7N/8 are compared based on the result of 2nd comparison.

Based on this, we know that:

Elements requiring 1 comparison: 1
Elements requiring 2 comparisons: 2
Elements requiring 3 comparisons: 4

Therefore, Elements requiring I comparisons: 2^(I-1)

The maximum number of comparisons = Number of times N is divided by 2 so that result is 1 = Comparisons to reach 1st element = logN comparisons

I can vary from 0 to logN

Total number of comparisons = 1 * (Elements requiring 1 comparison) + 2 * (Elements requiring 2 comparisons) + ... + logN * (Elements requiring logN comparisons)

Total number of comparisons = 1 * (1) + 2 * (2) + 3 * (4) + ... + logN * (2^(logN-1))

Total number of comparisons = 1 + 4 + 12 + 32 + ... = 2^logN * (logN - 1) + 1

Total number of comparisons = N * (logN - 1) + 1

Total number of cases = N+1

Therefore, average number of comparisons = ( N * (logN - 1) + 1 ) / (N+1)

Average number of comparisons = N * logN / (N+1) - N/(N+1) + 1/(N+1)

The dominant term is N * logN / (N+1) which is approximately logN. Therefore, Average Case Time Complexity of Binary Search is O(logN).Let there be N distinct numbers: a1, a2, ..., a(N-1), aN

We need to find element P.

There are two cases:

**Case 1:** The element P can be in N distinct indexes from 0 to N-1.

**Case 2:** There will be a case when the element P is not present in the list.
There are N case 1 and 1 case 2. So, there are N+1 distinct cases to consider in total.

If element P is in index K, then Binary Search will do K+1 comparisons.

This is because:

The element at index N/2 can be found in 1 comparison as Binary Search starts from the middle.

Similarly, in the 2nd comparison, elements at index N/4 and 3N/4 are compared based on the result of the 1st comparison.

On this line, in the 3rd comparison, elements at index N/8, 3N/8, 5N/8, and 7N/8 are compared based on the result of the 2nd comparison.

Based on this, we know that:

Elements requiring 1 comparison: 1
Elements requiring 2 comparisons: 2
Elements requiring 3 comparisons: 4
Therefore, Elements requiring I comparisons: 2^(I-1)

The maximum number of comparisons = Number of times N is divided by 2 so that result is 1 = Comparisons to reach 1st element = logN comparisons

I can vary from 0 to logN

Total number of comparisons = 1 * (Elements requiring 1 comparison) + 2 * (Elements requiring 2 comparisons) + ... + logN * (Elements requiring logN comparisons)

Total number of comparisons = 1 * (1) + 2 * (2) + 3 * (4) + ... + logN * (2^(logN-1))

Total number of comparisons = 1 + 4 + 12 + 32 + ... = 2^logN * (logN - 1) + 1

Total number of comparisons = N * (logN - 1) + 1

Total number of cases = N+1

Therefore, average number of comparisons = ( N * (logN - 1) + 1 ) / (N+1)

Average number of comparisons = N * logN / (N+1) - N/(N+1) + 1/(N+1)

The dominant term is N * logN / (N+1) which is approximately logN. Therefore, the Average Case Time Complexity of Binary Search is `O(logN)`.

**Worst Case Time Complexity of Binary Search**

The worst case of Binary Search occurs when:

The element to search is in the first index or last index
In this case, the total number of comparisons required is logN comparisons.

Therefore, the Worst Case Time Complexity of Binary Search is `O(logN)`.